# Error C2146 and Error C4430 Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement some classes derived from one main class but I keep getting these errors and I have no idea where they are coming from.
Here are de erros:

Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error   6   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'filtername'

Here is the code:

Filter.H:

```
#ifndef _FILTER_H_
#define _FILTER_H_


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Image.h"

class Filter
{
public:
    Filter();
    ~Filter();
    virtual bool apply(Image& img, const string filtername);

};
#endif /*FILTER_H_*/
```

FilterGreen.H:

```
#pragma once
#include "Filter.h"
#include "Image.h"


using namespace std;

class FilterGreen : public Filter
{
public:

    FilterGreen();
    ~FilterGreen();
    bool apply(Image& img, const string filtername);
};
```

Image.h:

```
#ifndef __Image_H__
#define __Image_H__

enum ImageType
{
    ImageType_TYPE_RGB8,
    ImageType_TYPE_RGB24,
    ImageType_TYPE_RGB32
};


class Image
{
public:

    int width, height;
    ImageType type;
    unsigned char* data;
    unsigned int size;

    Image();
    ~Image();
};
#endif
```

The error is related to the line `virtual bool apply(Image& img, const string filtername);` in the `filter.h` file.

Comment: Even for someone working with VS frequently, those numbers alone are pretty useless.

Comment: The description for the error is:
Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'filtername'
Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
Sorry for the lack of info

Comment: Edit your question to provide the error text and line numbers please.

Comment: `virtual bool apply(Image& img, const std::string filtername);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would even drop the `const`, or pass a reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza It was just about pointing out the `std::`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, because I haven't seen your error message or the file from which you include these headers.

In the line `virtual bool apply(Image& img, const string filtername);` in filter.h, is `string` in scope?  I'm assuming that you mean `std::string`, because you include `<string>`, but you don't import it into the current namespace.  Try replacing `string` with `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It resolved the two erros I had but created another one:
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall Filter::apply(class Image &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?apply@Filter@@UAE_NAAVImage@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Thanks for your help. Any other files needed?

Comment: That's a linker error.  How is `Filter::apply` defined?

Comment: Filter::apply is defined in FilterGreen.cpp

bool FilterGreen::apply(Image& img, const std::string filtername){

 for (unsigned int f = 1; f < img.size; f += 3){

  img.data[f] = 0;
 }
 return true;
}

Comment: That's `FilterGreen::apply`, not `Filter::apply`.  If `Filter::apply` doesn't have a definition, you need to flag it as pure virtual: `virtual bool apply(Image& img, const std::string filtername) = 0;`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Yes I was missing the '=0'in the pure virtual function definition! Thanks my problem is solved!